# symfony2 multiple forms of same type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

So I have a symfony2 project that I am working on. I have a few entities, Projects, Tasks, and TaskNotes. A Project has many Tasks, and Tasks have many TaskNotes. I have a page on the site that displays all of tasks associated with a Project, and each of those tasks has a form displayed under it that I can use to add a TaskNote to the Task.

I do not know the best method to pass these forms from my controller to my template and render them. Do I need to generate multiple form entities? One for each potential new TaskNote that could be added? Or can I use one TaskNote form entity somehow?

My current strategy is to loop through all the tasks in the controller, and for each of them I create a TaskNote form, change the name of the TaskNote form to dev_project_tasknote_X (where X is the taskID), put them into an array called $newTaskNoteForms where the index is the TaskId, and then render them in twig when I loop through my tasks like {{ form_widget(newTaskNoteForms[X].name) }} (again where X is the taskId). Then back in the controller when I process the request I will loop through the tasks again, and if $request->request->has('dev_task_note_X') I'll persist the TaskNote Entity.

Comment: You want to add more than one tasknote to the task? Like have a form of tasks and inside it you want to add as many tasknotes as you want? If yes, this is called "form collection" in symfony. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Negative, I want to display many tasks on the page, each with a form to add one note. Appreciate the reply though.

Comment: >Tasks have many TaskNotes -> Then TaskNotes are an embedded form. I agree with  Koalabaerchen. Can you explain why you say it is not a collection ?
You can perfectly achieve this using the embedded forms model.

Comment: I could see where it would be an embedded form, but since I am not editing any part of the task, would it not end up being a TaskType form, with an Embedded TaskNote Type and nothing else? Also if I was trying to add multiple notes to the same task one one page I would agree that a collection would be appropriate, but since I am just trying to add one I didn't think it applied. I could be misunderstanding.... thanks for the input.